# Syntax error in AWS lambda index.js file

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I keep getting following error from AWS lambda. I am not sure what kind of an syntax error is this.Can anyone please explain what might be happening here?

```
Syntax error in module 'index': SyntaxError
at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
at Module._compile (module.js:373:25)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
at Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/index.js:60:14)
at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
```

Here is my Index.js file at line 60:

```
var DocumentDBClient = require('documentdb').DocumentClient;
var HttpStatusCodes = { NOTFOUND: 404 };
var config = require('./config');
var dbTask = require('./Task');   // <-- index.js line 60
```

Here is my Task.js File:

```
var DocumentDBClient = require('documentdb').DocumentClient;
 var docdbUtils = require('./DBUtils');


function Task(documentDBClient, databaseId, collectionId) {
   this.client = documentDBClient;
   this.databaseId = databaseId;
   this.collectionId = collectionId;
   this.databaseUrl = `dbs/${databaseId}`;
   this.collectionUrl = `${this.databaseUrl}/colls/${collectionId}`;

   this.database = null;
   this.collection = null;
}

Task.prototype = {
     init: function (callback) {
         var self = this;

         docdbUtils.getOrCreateDatabase(self.client, self.databaseId, function (err, db) {
             if (err) {
                 callback(err);
             } else {
                 self.database = db;
                 docdbUtils.getOrCreateCollection(self.client, self.database._self, self.collectionId, function (err, coll) {
                     if (err) {
                         callback(err);

                     } else {
                         self.collection = coll;
                     }
                 });
             }
         });
     },


     find: function (querySpec, callback) {
         var self = this;

         self.client.queryDocuments(self.collectionUrl, querySpec).toArray(function (err, results) {
             if (err) {
                 callback(err);
             } else {
                 callback(null, results);
             }
         });
     },


     updateDocument: function (item, callback) {
         var self = this;
         let documentUrl = `${this.collectionUrl}/docs/${item.id}`;
         self.getDocument(item, function (err, doc) {
             if (err) {
                 callback(err);
             } else {
                 self.client.replaceDocument(documentUrl, item, function (err, replaced) {
                     if (err) {
                         callback(err,null);
                     } else {
                         callback(null, replaced);
                     }
                 });
             }
         });
     },


     getDocument: function (itemId, callback) {
         var self = this;

         var querySpec = {
             query: 'SELECT * FROM root r WHERE r.id = @id',
             parameters: [{
                 name: '@id',
                 value: itemId
             }]
         };

         self.client.queryDocuments(self.collectionUrl, querySpec).toArray(function (err, results) {
             if (err) {
                 callback(err);
             } else {
                 if(results.length > 0)
                    callback(null, results[0]);
                else
                    callback(null, null);
             }
         });
     },

    addDocument: function (item, callback) {
         var self = this;
         self.client.createDocument(self.collectionUrl, item, function (err, doc) {
             if (err) {
                 callback(err);

             } else {
                 callback(null, doc);
             }
         });
     },

    //Queries
    getUserPrimary : function (itemId, callback){
        var self = this;
        var querySpec = {
             query: 'SELECT VALUE r.primary FROM root r WHERE r.id = @id',
             parameters: [{
                 name: '@id',
                 value: itemId
             }]
         };
        self.client.queryDocuments(self.collectionUrl, querySpec).toArray(function (err, results) {
             if (err) {
                 callback(err);
             } else {
                 callback(null, results[0]);
             }
         });
     },

    getUserAll : function (itemId, callback){
        var self = this;
        var querySpec = {
             query: 'SELECT VALUE r.ABCD FROM root r WHERE r.id = @id',
             parameters: [{
                 name: '@id',
                 value: itemId
             }]
         };
        self.client.queryDocuments(self.collectionUrl, querySpec).toArray(function (err, results) {
             if (err) {
                 callback(err);
             } else {
                 callback(null, results);
             }
         });
     },
};

module.exports = Task;
```

Comment: Is this just a matter of trying to run this on a non-ES6 version of node? The syntax error may be due to an older version of node that doesn't have template strings.

Comment: Jacob,Thanks for your answer. I figured, the default noje.js version on AWS is 4.3 whereas I have been writing code in Node.js 6.1 . Silly SIlly SIlly. :/

Comment: what i do is use `nvm` and create an `.nvmrc` file with '4.3' in it in the directory that I code up my lambda in, then I can test that it works against the  version used by lambda.